# The fate of "the Lord of the Ashtray"

Tags: world-of-darkness, orpheus

Back in 2002, the Fans that made Orpheus held a contest to make a Samual Haight-themed campaign. [The Lord of the Ashtray](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/145008/lord-ashtray) won.

Through sheer luck, the web archive crawled the fans' website [starting in 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20180529045300/http://ravil.rooms.cwal.net:80/flatline/samhaight.html) and conserved at least the existence of the page and the HTTP content on it. However... the adventure and downloadable files were not conserved.

Is it lost together with the Project Flatline website after it stopped being responsive (according to my browser: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`) after the [last successful crawl in February 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20200217223525/http://ravil.rooms.cwal.net/flatline/samhaight.html)?